# display specific widget to a page

Tags: php, widgets

im trying to display a specific widget i need for the header current im using a code to display all widgets but my problem is that if I add additional widgets it will destroy my site.

```
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar2' ); ?>

                    <?php else : ?>

                        <!-- This content shows up if there are no widgets defined in the backend. -->

                        <div class="alert-box">Please activate some Widgets.</div>

                    <?php endif; ?>
```

code im using..

im trying to display this widget

http://prntscr.com/4yupl1

i tried to use this code to call the widget but nothing happens I must be putting the wrong name of the widget or the code. i don't about backend code.

```
<?php the_widget( 'WP_Language_Switcher' ); ?>
```

Comment: can i use this to display the widget?
http://prntscr.com/4yv0n0

Comment: Where is widget coming from? I don't think it's native WordPress one.

Comment: its coming from a plugin. is it plausible to call? or i need another plugin to call it?

Comment: You probably just need to figure out correct class name from the plugin's source.

Comment: yeah the problem is i dont know the name of the widget. i tried to get it using the developer tool for chrome checking the class and id. i tried to use both but nothing happen i dont know if i the widget is wrong or the syntax Im using to call is wrong...

`<?php the_widget( 'WP_Language_Switcher' ); ?> `

I'm using this code btw

Comment: You need to look at the PHP code for class name, output to the page is irrelevant for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create new widget area.

```
     function header_widget_areas() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'header', 'header' ),
        'id' => 'header',
        'description' => __( 'Insert something for about us text.', 'header' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget span3">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ) );



}
add_action('widgets_init', 'header_widget_areas');
```

Then place your widget in that area from appearance. 
Then in your template where you want to display widget past this code.

```
<?php if (function_exists('header_widget_areas')): ?>

                                                <?php dynamic_sidebar('header'); ?> 
                                            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this doesnt actually answers my question but this is the best alternative so far.

Comment: how can add a condition if my site has a multilanguage like abc.com/abd/en for english site and abc.com/abd/da for dansk

Comment: I have no knowledge about that language condition. Sorry dear.